# I'm rigging this low poly model and every time I rotate the leg it starts to warp and shrink

Tags: rigging, armature, bones

[image: This is the sort of deformation I'm talking about]

I'm still new to blender and I've attached the bones via vertex points, haven't done any weight painting, any help would be appreciated. Also any guides for this sort of thing would be great, I've looked at a few but they tackle the topic in different ways that confuse me.

Comment: hello, please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: @moonboots I uploaded the file, thank you!

Comment: you need to share the link (URL) it will give you, please copy paste it here  ;)

Comment: @moonboots https://pasteall.org/blend/a0eab9d2b65b4bf1bca378aeda6db853, alright I think thats it

Comment: @moonboots thank you so much for your help, are you able to give me a brief explanation and how the fix worked and how I got there in the first place>

Comment: Maybe you've duplicated and mirrored some parts with SX-1, which inverts faces. As for the rigging, inverted faces lead to bad rigging, because it considers the outside as inside and vice versa, so it will incorrectly bend the mesh

Answer (score 1):

You have inverted normals as you can see. In *Edit* mode, select all and press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> to recalculate. Then reparent *With Automatic Weight*.

[image]